# error: reached end of file while parsing - java

Tags: java, binary

So I am working on my homework for my java class. I am trying to code a simple program that converts a 4-byte binary number into decimal. Now, I will admit that I used some lines I found through searches. So, I am not really sure what is happening with my code. My source is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class B2Dconversion
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    { 

    System.out.println("Hello, I am so glad you stopped by my little place I call home.");
    System.out.println("I have been told I have many talents, but the one that I can do for you now.");
    System.out.println("What I would like you to do is enter a 4-byte binary number and I will convert it for you into decimal.");
    try 
            {                                    //thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ie) {
            }
    System.out.println("..... Oh you don't know what a 4-byte binary number is?");
    System.out.println("That is just a 4 digit number consisting of any combination of 1's and 0's.");
    System.out.println("i.e. 0001 or 1111 or 1010 etc...");
    System.out.println("So go ahead and enter any 4 digit number in the space below and I will convert it to its binary counterpart.");

    int binary1, decimal1; // declaration of the integer variables

    binary1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    decimal1 = Interger.parseInt(binary1,2); // converts binary to decimal see java documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

    System.out.println("You entered " + binary1); // confirmation of the input
    System.out.println("Abra-Cadabra");
    System.out.println("Bippity Boppity");
    System.out.println("Beep, Bop, Boop, eeerrrrr");

    System.out.println("Now that is done the results are ");
    System.out.println( + decimal1);
    }
```

I get 1 error when I compile and the only thing that displays is B2Dconversion.java:42: error: reached end of file while parsing

Any help I can get would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not balanced parenthesis. that's why you get that error. you have to close the class with `}` character at the end of the file. if you have googled that error. you can find similar questions on stackoverlow

[Reached End of file while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679523/reached-end-of-file-while-parsing)

[Java compile error: "reached end of file while parsing }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934412/java-compile-error-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing)

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Now for the real fun.... I have a new error though. 

'B2Dconversion.java:34: error: cannot find symbol d1 = Interger.parsInt(b1,2);

symbol: variable Interger
location: class B2Dconversion'

I had to make some changes so here is the snippet of code I believe it is referencing.

  int b1, d1; // declaration of the integer variables
  
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  b1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  d1 = Interger.parseInt(b1,2);

Comment: `d1` simbol is not in your posted code. that's weird. what is the actual error?

Comment: sorry I modified the code to simplify the variables,

Comment: you didn't define 'keyboard'. define that before use

Comment: Doesn't this define 'keyboard'?
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: `nextInt()` method return an integer not boolean. you don't want to parse that into `parseInt` method.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for correcting this error? or should I just re-write this section of the code to utilize another method to convert the binary to decimal?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing to get the program to work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ch2PP11BinaryToDecimal
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    { 

    System.out.println("Hello, I am so glad you stopped by my little place I call home.");
    System.out.println("I have been told I have many talents, but the one that I can do for you now.");
    System.out.println("What I would like you to do is enter a 4-byte binary number and I will convert it for you into decimal.");
    try 
            {                                    //thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ie) {
            }
    System.out.println("..... Oh you don't know what a 4-byte binary number is?");
    System.out.println("That is just a 4 digit number consisting of any combination of 1's and 0's.");
    System.out.println("i.e. 0001 or 1111 or 1010 etc...");
    System.out.println("So go ahead and enter any 4 digit number in the space below and I will convert it to its binary counterpart.");

    String binaryNumber;
    int eights, fours, twos, ones, decimalNumber; // declaration of the integer variables

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    binaryNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
    decimalNumber = 0;
    decimalNumber = decimalNumber+(binaryNumber.charAt(0)-'0')*8;
    decimalNumber = decimalNumber+(binaryNumber.charAt(1)-'0')*4;
    decimalNumber = decimalNumber+(binaryNumber.charAt(2)-'0')*2;
    decimalNumber = decimalNumber+(binaryNumber.charAt(3)-'0')*1;

    System.out.println("You entered " + binaryNumber); // confirmation of the input
    System.out.println("Abra-Cadabra");
    System.out.println("Bippity Boppity");
    System.out.println("Beep, Bop, Boop, eeerrrrr");
    try 
            {                                    //thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ie) {
            }
    System.out.println("Now that is done the results is ");
    System.out.println(decimalNumber);
    }
}
```