# Reached end of file while parsing (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, unexpectendoffile

Wrote some code to find roots of a polynomial via the quadratic formula, but it is reaching the end of the file while parsing.  All my curly braces are closed, so I'm not sure where the error is.  Can anybody see why?

```
        public static void main(String[] args){ //execute the previously defined methods to calculate the quadratic equation.
        while (cont){
        Scanner Ascanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Created a new scanner variable for the A value.
        double a = Ascanner.nextInt(); //Storing the next integer of that scanner variable for an Integer of the A value.
        double b = Ascanner.nextInt(); //Storing the next integer of that scanner variable for an Integer for the B value.
        double c = Ascanner.nextInt(); //Storing the next integer of that scanner variable for an Integer of the C value.
        //Finding the radicand
        double tem1 = handleradicand(a,b,c);
        System.out.println("radicand" + tem1);
        //Finding the radical
        if (tem1 <= 0) {
           double tem2 = sub_0rootradicand(tem1);
           System.out.println("radical" + tem2);
           double tem3 = divideBby2a (b,a);
           double tem4 = divideRADby2a (tem2, a);
           double firstX = findroot1 (tem3, tem4);
           double secondX = findroot2 (tem3, tem4);
           System.out.println("Your roots are X = i " + firstX + " " + "and X = i " + secondX);
       }  else {
           double tem2 = rootradicand(tem1);

           System.out.println("radical" + tem2);
           double tem3 = divideBby2a (b,a);
           double tem4 = divideRADby2a (tem2, a);
           double firstX = findroot1 (tem3, tem4);
           double secondX = findroot2 (tem3, tem4);
       }
        system.out.println("Again? (y/n)");
        resp = Ascanner.next();
       if(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || resp.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
           if(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            cont = false;
            } else {
            cont = true;
            }
        }

}
```

EDIT:  Was missing curly braces at the end, fixed.

Comment: Sounds like you get this error because you read all the data....

Comment: Stack trace? Which line causes the error, specifically?

Comment: Any exception from your console?!

Comment: i dont know what stack trace means, i am very new, i think i get the error in the last line because i get a little red line at the end of the final bracket, but idk.

Comment: Could you post your error message?IDE message?

Comment: There only one error I see is in `system.out.println("Again? (y/n)");` It must be `System` (first letter in capital)

Comment: "reached end of file while parsing" the while loop is not missing a closing brace, and i capitalized system and it is still giving me the error

Comment: Plesse post the whole code, not just the function and which IDE you are using

Comment: Right, sorry. I counted one for the class, which is usually included. It would help if you formatted your code readably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if your curly parenthesis are not ending completeley or maybe there could be extra parenthesis in the end. So check your opening and closing parenthesis of each functions and class. This might solve your problem. I have experienced this compiler error before and the above solution worked every time.

Comment: its not my whole code, i have methods defind before that and all of that including the code i showed is within a public class

Comment: Yes I just realised that. I was just editing my answer. Try to cross-check your code for what I just said above.

Comment: Here is a link which tries to say exactly what I want to, [braces-Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679523/reached-end-of-file-while-parsing?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing curly braces at the end, fixed

Comment: You should accept burglar hobbits answer as solution as he invested his time to solve your problem and he solved it.

Comment: Good point, done.  Thank you